# Why does auto-import of some packages not work?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, auto-import

Intellij auto-import does not work for some packages.
e.g. here is a simple [example project on Github](https://github.com/tmtron/intellij-import-test) where the auto-import from the [change-case](https://github.com/blakeembrey/change-case) package does not work:

[image]

1. When I click CTRL+SPACE for a function that exists in the package, I see no suggestions
2. When I manually add the import (e.g. uncomment this line), it compiles fine
3. I noticed that the `change-case` package has type defs in the subdirs `dist` and `dist.es2015`
   I guess this is the reason: if so, how can we solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-import only works for packages added as direct dependencies. Adding `"snake-case": "^3.0.3"` to `package.json` should help:

[image]

Comment: yes that makes sense. Maybe the authors of `change-case` will improve this: see [change-case#05](https://github.com/blakeembrey/change-case/issues/95#issuecomment-619330626)